# Why is `++` for Haskell List implemented recursively and costs O(n) time?

Tags: list, pointers, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

As I understood, a List in Haskell is a similar to a Linked-List in C language.

So for expressions below:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
a ++ b
```

Haskell implement this in a recursive way like this:

```
(++) (x:xs) ys = x:xs ++ ys
```

The time complexity for that is `O(n)`..

However, I was wondering why can't I implement `++` more efficiently.

The most efficient way may be like this:

1. make a copy(fork) of `a`, let's call it `a'`, there may be some tricks to do this in `O(1)` time
2. make the last element of `a'` to point to the first element of `b`. This can be done easily in `O(1)` time..

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: I like algorithms which depend on "there *may* be some tricks to do this in constant time". :)

Comment: None of the language you used ("pointers", "copy", "linked list") make much sense in the context of Haskell's semantics. `[a]` is not at all a linked list, although it might resemble one in the way GHC lays it out in memory (or it might not, or it might not exist in memory at all)

Comment: How do you plan to copy *n* things without taking O(*n*) time?

Comment: @immibis @jalf only copy the part which will be changed later, which is the last element of `a`

Comment: @hanfeisun But then the second-to-last element needs to point to the new last element. And then the third-to-last element needs to point to the new second-to-last element.

Comment: You'd be right if lists were trees, then you could allocate a new root node pointing to both the original lists.

Comment: @immibis: NO, that tree data structure wouldn't save you. When you finally iterate over the list, the additional treatment of additional root node would add a constant-time overhead to the access of every element of the first part of the list - effectively adding the O(n) additional time again!

Comment: @mastov Iterating over a list is always at least O(n), so in terms of big-O notation, nothing changes.

Comment: @immibis: That simplification only works, if you iterate at least once per application of `++`, but not in general. Just take the naïve `myrev` operation as example: `myrev [] = [] ; myrev (x:xs) = myrev xs ++ [x]`. For a list of length n it applies `++` n times before someone iterates over the result, so in your tree it would add n nodes: `CombList (CombList (CombList ... [x3]) [x2]) [x1]`. Accessing the first element `xn` of the reversed list requires going through all n nodes, accessing the second element n-1 nodes etc., so it's quadratic, which is only possible if you consider `++` linear.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's pretty much what the recursive solution does. It's the copying of `a` which takes O(n) (where `n` is the length of `a`. The length of `b` doesn't affect the complexity).

There is really no "trick" to copy a list of `n` elements in O(1) time.

Answer (score 12):

See the *copy(fork)* part is the problem - the recursive solution does exactly this (and you really have to do it, because you have to adjust all the pointers for the elements in the `a` list.

Let's say `a = [a1,a2,a3]` and `b` is some list.

You have to make a new copy of `a3` (let's call it `a3'`) because it should now no longer point to an empty list but to the start of `b`.

Then you have to make a copy of the second to last element `a2` too because it must point to `a3'` and finally - for the same reason - you have to create a new copy of `a1` too (pointing to `a2'`).

This is exactly what the recursive definition does - it's no problem with the algorithm - it's a problem with the data-structure (it's just not good with concatenation).

If you don't allow mutability and want the structure of a list you can really do nothing else.

You have this in other langs. too if they provide immutable data - for example in .net strings are immutable - so there is almost the same problem with string-concatenation as is here (if you concat lots of strings your program will perform poorly). There are workaround (`StringBuilder`) that will deal better with the memory footprint - but of course those are no longer immutable data-structures.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that concatenation in constant time, simply because the immutability of the data structure doesn't allow it.

---

You might think that you could do something similar to the "cons" operator (`:`) that adds an additional element `x0` to the **front** of a list `oldList=[x1,x2,x3]` (resulting in `newList=(x0:oldLIst)`) without having to run through the whole list. But that's just because you don't touch the existing list `oldList`, but simply reference it.

```
x0  :  ( x1  :  ( x2  :  ( x3  :  [] )   )   )
^        ^
newList  oldList
```

But in your case (`a ++ b`) we are talking about updating a reference deep within the data structure. You want to replace the `[]` in `1:(2:(3:[]))` (the explicit form of `[1,2,3]`) by the new tail `b`. Just count the parenthesis and you'll see that we have to go deep inside to get to the `[]`. That's always expensive because we have to duplicate the whole outer part, in order to make sure that `a` stays unmodified. In the resulting list, where would the old `a` point to in order to have the unmodified list?

```
1  :  ( 2  :  ( 3  :  b  )   )
^                     ^
a++b                  b
```

That's impossible in the same data structure. So we need a second one:

```
1  :  ( 2  :  ( 3  :  []  )   )
^
a
```

And that means duplicating those `:` nodes, which necessarily costs the mentioned linear time in the first list. The "copy(fork)" that you mentioned is therefore, differently from what you said, *not* in O(1).

---

> make a copy(fork) of a, let's call it a', there may be some tricks to do this in O(1) time

When you talk about a "trick" to fork something in constant time, you probably think about not actually making a full copy, but creating a reference to the original `a`, with the changes stored as "annotations" (like the hint: "modification to tail: use `b` instead of `[]`").

But that's what Haskell, thanks to its lazyness, does anyway! It doesn't immediately execute the O(n) algorithm, but just "remembers" that you wanted a concatenated list, until you actually access its elements. But that doesn't save you from paying the cost in the end. Because even though in the beginning the reference was cheap (in O(1), just like you wanted), when you do access the actual list elements, every instance of the `++` operator adds a little overhead (the cost of "interpreting the annotation" that you added to your reference) to the access of every element in the first part of the concatenation, effectively adding the O(n) cost finally.